# what's the difference between route and route -n in linux, why can't i get the right IP with "route" sometimes?

Tags: linux

I type route, the result is strange, as shown in the pic, why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rEKw.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "the right IP"? Please describe your expectations and problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

From the `man` you can read:

> **-n**
>   show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host names. This is useful if you are trying to determine why the route to your nameserver has vanished.

If you omit the `-n` option you will see a hostname instead of the numerical IP address.